# Referencing a Third Object in Trigger

Tags: apex

Very very new to Apex. This is actually my first Apex project. Here's what I'm trying to do - I have two custom objects related to Opportunity. When an opportunity is won, I need to take values from the records on the first custom object, and create new records in the second custom object using values from the first.

Somewhere in my for( ) block, I need to be able to assign a variable that references the Object_A List. . . I think.

Any input is greatly appreciated!!!

```
trigger Win_Opportunity on Opportunity (before update) {
    List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();

    Map<Id,Opportunity> oppWithB = new Map<Id,Opportunity>(
        [Select Id, StageName FROM opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.New]);

    List<Object_A__c> PSList = new List<Object_A__c>();

    Map<id, Object_A__c> oppWithPS = new Map<id, Object_A__c>(
        [SELECT id, contact_name__c, opportunity__c FROM Object_A__c WHERE opportunity__c IN : Trigger.New]);

   for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){
       if ( o.StageName == 'Closed Won'){
       Object_B__c b = new Object_B__c(); 
    b.Name = 'Bench';
    b.contact_Name__c = //Need to be able to set new value to Contact_Name__c from Object_A
    b.Project__c = o.id ;
    insert b; 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please specify if object A have multiple records for the same opportunity @sfAndTri

Comment: If `object_a__c` has an `opportunity__c` field, then there is a 1: *n* relationship that also needs to be resolved. Can you help us understand which `object_a__c` record would be needed (and indeed how you can be certain that every `opportunity` record *has* at least one `object_a__c` child record?

Comment: @Peter Doesn't need to have at least one record to do this if you iterate on object_a__c records. Part of what would be helpful to know is if it's a M-D relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you phrase your question sounds as if you need a new object_b__c record for *every* object_a__c record associated to every opportunity that has been closed. So, making that assumption...

In that instance, I might to do this:

```
trigger Win_Opportunity on Opportunity (after update) {
  List<object_b__c> newBList = new List<object_b__c>();
  List<Id> newlyClosedOpptyIds = new List<Id>();

  for (Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
    if (o.StageName = 'Closed Won' && o.StageName != Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id).StageName){
      newlyClosedOpptys.add(o.Id);
    }
  }

  for (object_a__c a : [select Id, Contact_Name__c, Opportunity__c
                        where Opportunity__c IN newlyClosedOpptyIds]){

    Object_B__c b = new Object_B__c(); 
    b.Name = 'Bench';
    b.contact_Name__c = a.Contact_Name__c
    b.Project__c = a.Opportunity__c ;

    newBList.add(b);

  }

  insert newBList;

}
```

Some choices to be aware of...

Opportunity is typically a busy object. If you had other triggers going off on opportunity (either now, or in the future), you'll need to think more about how this may interact with them.

I prefer to put such triggers as *after* so that your custom validation rules can cause the transaction to stop before executing trigger logic.

If you only want this to happen the first time a record is saved with the `Opportunity.StageName` of "Closed Won", you'll want to do a check on Trigger.OldMap to ensure this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a best practice to utilize the one trigger per object structure and use helper classes to do the heavy lifting. You should also investigate using nested SOQL queries when trying to traverse down (if you know which record it is that you're looking for, i.e. most recent, accepted etc.).

Here's what I would do if I were you:

Trigger:

```
trigger Opportunity_Trigger on Opportunity (before update) {

    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        Opportunity_Methods.closedWonOpp(trigger.newMap, trigger.oldMap);
    }
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public class Opportunity_Methods{

    public static void closedWonOpp(Map<Id,Opportunity> newMap, Map<Id,Opportunity> oldMap){
        List<Object_B__c> objectBList = new List<Object_B__c>();

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id, StageName, (SELECT Id, Contact_Name__C, Opportunity__c FROM Object_A__r ORDER BY CreatedDated Desc Limit 1) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :newMap.keyset()]){
        if(o.Object_A__r.size() > 0 && newMap.get(o.id).isWon == True && oldMap.get(o.id).isWon == False){
            Object_B__c objB = new Object_B__c();
            objb.Opportunity__c = o.id;
            objb.Contact_Name__c = o.Object_A__r[0].Contact_Name__c;
            objectBList.add(objb);
        }
        }
        if(objectBList.size() > 0){
            try{
                insert objectBList;
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }
}
```